# Transcribing the funeral record of Peter Pinnart from Hundshausen

Tags: germany, palaeography, transcriptions, german-language, kurrent

[image]

I'm having difficulty reading the handwriting for this entry, and could use some assistance transcribing the record.

I read it as "aus der pfalz von Handschuhsheim, bei Walburg burtig", or "From the Palatinate of Handschuhsheim, near Walburg born".  I can't quite figure that out combination of place names, however; there is a Walburg about 60 km to the north-east of Hundshausen, while the only Handschuhsheim I can find is indeed in the Palatinate, some 200+ km to the south-west, next to Heidelberg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the page is truncated. The word before "bürtig" looks like "delberg" to me (the left-most arc belongs to the "j" in "januari"), and note the start of some letter right after "bey" (row above, far right). So my opinion it that it says "Handschuhsheim bey Heidelberg".